# String Pattern Matching Check in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need Idea on developing utility class which handles String comparison based on pattern For example :  If the String is in this Format `A_B_C_asdasd_asasd`, If i want to compare only Part Exactly `B_C` section with other string,  utility class needs to tell whether string is valid or not, say If the FileName is `F1_2014_11_12_2013345980.dat`, I would like to compare part of string say `2014_11` contains a string like `2014`, I don't search in entire string, I'm looking for generic method, where application will have config value which tell me pattern to search in file name format and contains target string. If no value is mentioned in config, we can have entire File Name matching. Can we do it `regex` to compare pattern wise string

Comment: can you not use the `Contains()` method ?

Comment: you can use Regex.IsMatch() function to match substring in string

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex, grouping your patterns:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // First we see the input string.
        string input = "/content/alternate-1.aspx";

        // Here we call Regex.Match.
        Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"content/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.aspx$",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Here we check the Match instance.
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
            string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HI lcaro, My requirement is if my string is W_X_Y_Z, If the format of file is in above and user mentioned i would require X_Y section, I should able to get the X_Y Section part of String

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need to be quite so elaborate. If your attempting to validate only a *portion* of your data, then avoid the extra overhead of the *Regular Expression*.

```
private static bool FindPortion(string input, string pattern)
{
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern))
          if(input.Contains(pattern))
               return true;

     return false;
}
```

So in theory you have:

- Input: `11_10_2014_Random.dat`
- Pattern: `10_2014`
- Result: `True`

The *Contain* will ensure that the following character order is met, before returning a boolean of *true* or *false*.

> This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and
>   culture-insensitive) comparison. The search begins at the first
>   character position of this string and continues through the last
>   character position

So due to that limitation on *case*, you could either use `ToLower()` or `ToUpper()` or implement a `String.Compare` with *Culture Info* to account for that variant.  Based on current information and type of data the *Case Sensitivity* doesn't appear to be an issue.

Comment: The OP is looking for pattern matching, not string matching